# Can I create a working set with the files open in the current editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, working-set

Is it possible for Eclipse to create a new working set with all of the files open in the current (Java) editor?

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to manually select each file in the project explorer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the case!

Comment: Maybe mylyn could a little bit help. There are can be define contexts. You can add and remove file to contexts. But a context could dynamic grow too.

Comment: another one, where you can use reg expression, https://code.google.com/p/javadude/wiki/DynamicWorkingSets

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1:** Check out the [Extended VS Presentation](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html) plugin.

After installing, you can go to `Window > Editing Sessions > Save Opened Editors to Session` to save your opened files as a list. You can have any number of file sets (called "sessions" in the plugin).

To reopen a previous set of files, go to `Window > Editing Sessions > Load Session`.

**Compatibility Note:** The plugin is stated to support Eclipse only up to 3.8, but I was able to install it in 4.5.2 just fine. It seems that the theme is not present, but the `Editing Sessions` menu option is definitely there.

---

**Option #2:** Just go with [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) (included with nearly every Eclipse build now). Mylyn does do a bit more than requested, going as far as collapsing what it determines to be irrelevant code blocks and even offering a filtered view of your file system (this can be disabled by turning off the `Focus on Active Task` toggle in your file explorer).

To see Mylyn in action:

1. Open your Task List view (`Window > Show View > Task List`).
2. Right-click in the white space.
3. In the context menu, select `New > Local Task`.
4. Enter a name for the task.
5. Press `Ctrl + S` to save.
6. At the top left, click the bluish-gray circle to "activate" the task. (This can also be done by going to the Task List view, right-clicking the task, then clicking `Activate...`. ***Warning:*** Activating a new task will close all of your opened editor tabs.
7. As you open files, they will be added to the active task's "context." You can manipulate the context by double-clicking your task in the Task List view then clicking on the Context tab at the bottom of the task editor. Right-click an element and select `Remove from Context` to disassociate it from the task.

**Tip:** When you're done working on a particular task, be sure to go to the Task List view, right-click the task, and choose `Deactivate` to prevent files from being added to a task's context unintentionally.